# Is the survival function the same as the upper tail?

Tags: distributions

Are the two synonymous? The reason I am asking is that I have a paper that calculates a certain p-value as the upper tail of the hypergeometric distribution:

$\Sigma_{k}^{m} = \frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{N-m}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$

I want to implement their proposal using Python. [Scipy offers a hypergeometric distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hypergeom.html#scipy.stats.hypergeom) and it can calculate the survival function of that distribution from a given point. So I am wondering, are the two the same? Can I just use that function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  By definition, the survival function is $S(X = x) = Pr(X > x) = 1 - F(X = x)$ where $F$ is the CDF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the same as upper tail. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function

Comment: I found that page too, but it does not mention any relationship to the upper tail, so I was unsure.

Comment: Well upper tail is by definition P(X>x).